# Calculate the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^ne^{in}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence

For this I use the root criterion $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$.

How the series is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^ne^{in}$ we can see that $a_n=e^{in}$. Then

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|e^{in}|}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{(e^i)^n}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}e^i=e^i$.

Then $R=e^i$

But they give me the following conditions: Let $r$ be the radius of convergence, then

if $R\in \mathbb{R}$ whit $R>0$ then $r=\frac{1}{R}$

if $R=0$ then $r=\infty$

inf $R=\infty$ then $r=0$

But I found $R=e^i$ and it does not meet any of the three conditions. What can be done in these cases?

Comment: $|e^{in}|=1{}$.

Comment: @KentaS So what it does is just take the magnitude of $e^{in}$?

Comment: Your series is $\sum_n(ze^{I})^n=\frac{ze^i}{1-ze^i}$ valid for $|ze^i|=|z|<1$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thanks u

Comment: Use ratio test.  $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=|z|$.   $|z|\lt 1$ converges.  $|z|\gt 1$ diverges.  Radius of convergence $=1$.

Comment: If $x,y\in \Bbb R$ then $|x+iy|$ is defined to be $\sqrt {x^2+y^2}$.